# Is there a good hotkey cheatsheet for using Latex in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, latex

Is there a good hotkey cheatsheet for using Latex in Emacs? A few minutes of googling didn't turn up anything.

Comment: Which tex mode are you using? The basic one shipped with GNU emacs? Auctex? It matters.

Comment: Also, you'll find more emacs and latex questions and answers on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/latex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emacs

Comment: LaTeX questions should probably go to tex.stackexchange.com now. An emacs stackexchange is still much further away... http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/9013/emacs?referrer=2ewgqrTCMPDWgagw76fBpg2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the TeX mode shipped with Emacs has a cheatsheet (or a 'Refcard' as they're often called in the Emacs world). The closest thing around for AucTeX is its fine manual (PDF [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.pdf), the quickstart stuff begins on about p. 18).  Also note, RefTeX, a full featured citation manager for your BibTeX database (docs [here](http://www.xemacs.org/Documentation/packages/html/reftex.html)).  My own favorite citation manager is the slimmer [Ebib](http://ebib.sourceforge.net/).

Another great Emacs-Latex tool is [org-mode.](http://orgmode.org)  It works as a mode for the efficient outlining, writing, and editing of documents in its own lightweight markup syntax.  This can then be converted to a few different formats, including LaTeX.  Many of us do our writing in org-mode (which does have a [cheat sheet, here](http://orgmode.org/orgcard.pdf)) and then convert it to LaTeX.  Hard stuff may have to touched up by hand in LaTeX, but org gets the basics done nicely, and the 'basics' even do a pretty good job at things like tables, math, poetry, document structure, etc.

Answer (score 5):

When in doubt: C-h m for help on the current major mode.

Answer (score 0):

This one might be helpful.  I used the US Letter PDF.

http://www.stdout.org/~winston/latex/

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with emacs